# Why is O(n^2) the same as Θ(n^2)?

Tags: big-o

Today our professor mentioned that O(n^2) is the same as Θ(n^2).

I did not understand the explanation for that and I could not find something on the internet. Can please somebody explain it to me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for this question. Try programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Θ(n) and O(n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-on)

Comment: `f` is Big-theta(f) if it is both big-o(f) and big-omega(f) at the same thime.

Answer (score 1):

That's not true. For example, n = O(n<sup>2</sup>) (choose c = 1, n<sub>0</sub> = 0) but is not Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) (because lim<sub>n→∞</sub> n / n<sup>2</sup> = 0). I suspect that you either misheard the instructor, they misspoke, or they were talking about a specific context in which it was true that didn't generalize.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* the same. O is about upper bounds, Ω is about lower bounds, and Θ is about *both* upper and lower bounds.

As an example, a function f(n) = n is O(n^2), but *not* Θ(n^2), since we can't bound f from below by a multiple of n^2.

Comment: @glglgl: For future reference, how would I type a Θ on SO?

Comment: Copy & paste from somewhere else, e. g. the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Big O only gives an upper bound. Θ gives the lower bound as well. This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138212/difference-between-big-theta-and-big-o-notation-in-simple-language) should prove helpful. Your professor would be right if he said the reverse. As stated in the referenced question:

> Θ(f(n)) is also O(f(n)) but not the other way around.