# Does f in Ω(n) imply f is in O(n^2)?

Tags: big-o

As n ⇒ ∞, *f = Ω(n) ⇒ f = O(n^2).*

How can I show if this Omega and Big-O notation is correct?

Comment: Seems completely wrong from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/asymptotic_analysis.htm https://guide.freecodecamp.org/computer-science/notation/big-omega-notation/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138212/difference-between-big-theta-and-big-o-notation-in-simple-language

Comment: Are you sure that this is correct? If I have a linear lower bound, does this always mean that I also have a quadratic upper bound?

Answer (score 2):

It's false, and one counterexample is enough to show that it's false.

A simple counterexample is the function f(n) = n<sup>3</sup>, which is in Ω(n), but not in O(n<sup>2</sup>).