# How do I determine if a function is Big-Omega, Big-O, or both?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Can someone give some simple example functions and explain why they're Big-Omega, Big-O, or both? Also, what does it mean for a function to be both Big-Omega and Big-O?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Big-Theta and Big O notation in simple language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138212/difference-between-big-theta-and-big-o-notation-in-simple-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function is not Big-Omega, or Big-O, or Big-Theta. These are all methods of understanding behavior of a function, and all three can be applied, when analyzing any function.

Big O is an upper bound of function - so, maximum amount of memory function will use, or maximum amount of operations it needs to do before stop.
Big Omega - lower bound, minimum amount of operations / memory.

You can learn more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation, or just try searching for "asymptotic notation"

Comment: I see, thank you so much! I guess I need to improve my understanding of what asymptotic notation is then!