# Big O and Big Omega denotes Worst Case and Best case Respectively. Is it True?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I am just searching on google about Difference between Big Oh, Big Omega and Big Theta and found the first google search the geeksforgeeks article which says   Big oh (O) – Worst case,    Big Omega (Ω) – Best case and Big Theta (Θ) – Average case. Is this right?

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-big-oh-big-omega-and-big-theta/#:~:text=Big%2DO%20is%20a%20measure,Big%2DO%20and%20Big%2D%3F](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-big-oh-big-omega-and-big-theta/#:%7E:text=Big%2DO%20is%20a%20measure,Big%2DO%20and%20Big%2D%3F)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Big-Theta and Big O notation in simple language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138212/difference-between-big-theta-and-big-o-notation-in-simple-language)

Comment: @adnan_e is it mean that the article provided by geeksforgeeks is incorrect?

Comment: geeksforgeeks is wrong about a lot of things, this one is an example. I strongly recommend using more reliable sources.